# Issues outputting a dataset from a function

Tags: database, powershell, dataset

I have created a function that queries a given server/database and I'm trying output the data into a persisted dataset which I can use later. The issue is that the dataset is somehow being converted to an array when it output. As you can see in the script I create a dataset outside the function but when I pipe the function results into it , it changes to an array

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[parameter(mandatory = $true,helpmessage = "Enter envrionment name to create tdp files for. Eg 'LTS'")]
[string]$environment, 
[parameter(mandatory = $true,helpmessage = "Enter a log file desination and name eg. \\torvdb954\dba\refresh_output.txt" )]
[string]$logFile
)

"" > $logFile 

function Get-SQLdata 
($SQlServerName, $SQlDBName,$SQlQuery,$FLogfile)
{
        Try
        {
            $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQlServerName; Database = $SQlDBName; Integrated Security = True"

            $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQlQuery
            $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

            $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

            $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

            $Dataset = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
            $SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset) 
            return $Dataset.tables[0] 

        }
        Catch
        {
            "Error connecting to: " + $SQlServerName >> $logFile
            $_.ToString() >> $logFile
            $_.ToString()
            break
        }
        finally
        {
             $SqlConnection.Close()
        }

}

#control table data set
#declare your dataset outside the function so it is persisted
$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
$Dataset.GetType()
$CtrlSqlQuery = “select distinct instanceName,databaseName from pega_refresh_control where environment = '" + $environment + "'" 
$Dataset = Get-SQLdata -SQlServerName 'torvdb954' -SQlDBName 'DBA_pega_refresh' -FLogfile $logFile -SQlQuery $CtrlSqlQuery 
$Dataset.GetType()
$Dataset.tables[0]
```

Comment: Did you tried to return just `$Dataset` in your function, and not `$Dataset.tables[0]`?

Comment: Yes I tried returning just the $dataset but got the same results, it is still getting converted to an array. Here are the results

Comment: Property 'tables' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\Users\s80480\Documents\pega_refresh_create_restore_files.ps1:72 char:1
+ $Dataset.tables[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict